# Jquery Idle timer active not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I'm using JQuery idle-time plugin to automatically logs out a user after x mins of idle time.
But this idle/active time should be updated in the server as well. So trying to do an Ajax hit to the server inside the active.idleTimer function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        var timeout = 1800000;
        $(document).bind("idle.idleTimer", function () {
            window.location.href = "MyLOGOUT_URL";
        });
        $(document).bind("active.idleTimer", function () {
            $.ajax({ type: "POST", url : "My_URL" });
        });
        $.idleTimer(timeout);
    })(jQuery);

</script>
```

But this active.idleTimer is not called when the user is active. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work for me:

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/u3VKe/1/)**

Try putting your code in a jQM pageinit event and use .on() instead of bind:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#page1", function(){    
    $( document ).idleTimer( 5000 );
    $( document ).on( "idle.idleTimer", function(){
        $("#textinput-1").val('Idle at: ' + new Date());
    });

    $( document ).on( "active.idleTimer", function(){
        $("#textinput-1").val('Active again at: '  + new Date());
    });
});
```