# Jquery Global Event handler for hybrid mobile application

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery, logout, hybrid-mobile-app, user-inactivity

I have a hybrid mobile web application. The condition is user will be logged out if there is no activity (screen - touch, click, navigation etc) in app for 10 minutes.

The possible option is to register all available jquery mobile events on page id and record the last event timestamp. And logout user if no event is catched till 10 minutes.

But apart from this option is there any another better apporach to handle this scenario. If yes can it be done just by using the Jquery Mobile or does it need native plugins?

-Hanumant

Comment: How about the jQuery idle timer plugin. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21193593/jquery-idle-timer-active-not-firing/21194866#21194866 for a demo.

Comment: @ezanker thanks for the information, I will check this plugin if it fits my requirement.